# How to Url encode nested query strings

Tags: url-encoding

I have a the following url:

> http://www.test.com/?client=xyz&redirect_uri=http://www.xyz.com/x?p1=one&p2=two

How should I url encode these so that the browser does not interpret p1 and p2 as query strings of the `test.com` when they are actually part of the `redirect_uri` parameter.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: We need to know the language you are using otherwise we can't help you. If in JavaScript: question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/javascript-what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way to pass urls as url parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters)

Answer (score 12):

I quote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/javascript-what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters) that uses JavaScript. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1739132/revisions) by Dustin Boswell.

`encodeURIComponent()` should work.  For example,

```
'&url=' + encodeURIComponent("http://a.com/?q=query&n=10")
```

produces

```
"&url=http%3A%2F%2Fa.com%2F%3Fq%3Dquery%26n%3D10"
```

(which doesn't have any '&' or '?' in the value).
When your server gets this url, it should be able to decode that to get the original:

```
param["url"] = "http://a.com/?q=query&n=10"
```

I'm not sure what server you're using (e.g. Rails, Django, ...) but that should work "out of the box" on any normal system.