# How to pass a url address string as the parameter of a url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to pass a whole string `'/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1'` as a parameter of `actiondownloadsingle.htm` .

And I try to use the function encodeURI to encoding the string, but I failded, I can't get the correct value of the parameter origurl in server client, how can I do ? thanks!

```
$('.CssDownloadSingle').click(function () {
    var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);

    var origurl ='/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1'

    location.href = "actiondownloadsingle.htm?origurl=" +encodeURI(origurl);
});
```

Comment: Your question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/javascript-what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters).
Shortcut: use encodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode it as value of parameter:

```js
var origurl ='/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1';

alert(
  "encodeURIComponent: actiondownloadsingle.htm?origurl=" + encodeURIComponent(origurl) + "\r\n"
  + "encodeURI:                       actiondownloadsingle.htm?origurl=" + encodeURI(origurl)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I decode the value when I use Java  in server client?

Comment: You should already have it decoded when reading from _GET. Don't know much about Java back-end