# Twilio URL example for sending MMS

Tags: twilio

I'm a *very* new programmer and am messing around with creating URL's to send SMS or MMS messages via Twilio (my application is for home automation where if my camera detects motions, I want to send a still image to an MMS number via a URL).

Can someone post the format for sample URL for an MMS message that I can paste in a browser?

For example, if I have a To parameter of To=+7145551212 and a From parameter of From=+7145551111 and MediaURL=http://test.com/image.jpg, what would the format of the URL need to be?

I have my Account SID and AuthToken as well.  Just need an example of what a completed URL would look like so I can work backwards from there.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: What do you mean 'paste in a browser'? If you are trying to make an API call to Twilio's MMS endpoint from inside your application, you should use one of their official [helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) if available. If you are just trying to send a test MMS to yourself, you should use something like cURL or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). Don't use your browser's address bar to make API requests.

Comment: In general, you can send URL parameters by appending something like `?To=7145551212&From=7145551111` to the end of your URL. Adding something like a `MediaURL` is more complicated to pass as a URL parameter because the special characters need to be encoded so that your browser can parse it. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739132/5045925) as an example of what the result would look like. However, this is not what you should be doing in this case.

Read more about URL Parameters [here](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I *think* it would be this :

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages`

And then your parameters need to be in the POST body of the request, like

```
To=+7145551212&From=+7145551&MediaURL=http://test.com/image.jpg
```

But Brodan's comment is correct- you can't do this through just pasting a URL into your browser, because it's a POST request. You could use [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST), something like this :

```
curl --data "To=+7145551212&From=+7145551&MediaURL=http://test.com/image.jpg" https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/123456/Messages
```

But your best option would *really* be to use one of the Twilio helper libraries. [Here's](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) a link to their description of the endpoint, they have examples of using those libraries in a variety of languages.

*Note* : I have never used Twilio myself.