# Can you put a url in a url? OpenID Connect Redirect URI

Tags: http, url, https, openid-connect

I'm trying to setup a `redirect_uri` for `OpenId Connect`, but my provider `Okta` tells me it needs to be absolute. So I enter this url:

`http://example.com/callback` and okta accepts it.

Basically I want to open a sign-in window and redirect back to my server by adding a redirect url into the link.

full-link: `http://dev1234-okta.com/login/details?details$redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback$moredetails`

My question is, how can I set the redirect uri to be a url? When I put a url in the redirect uri, my popup just goes to the url and not the dev-1234-okta.com i'm specifying. Can urls have urls inside them? i.e. http link inside a url?

Comment: Why don't you reconstruct the uri by adding http:// back onto it, etc? If you're not certain what the uri will be, you can specify extra fields like encrypted=http, https etc.
Not sure what your limits are so just suggesting this in case you are able to do it. You can also try encoding your uri: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/javascript-what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters - not sure what language you're using though.

Comment: @bhow yeah url encoding was it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all i had to do was url encode my redirect_uri