# How to put url inside QR in odoo report

Tags: odoo, qr-code, qweb

I want to create a QR that redirects to a url with the following code:

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('QR', doc.id, 600, 50)" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
```

I want the value be like this:
https://example.com/doc.id

I idea how to concat 2 strings? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concat them right there:

```xml
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('QR', my_url + str(doc.id), 600, 50)" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
```

`my_url + str(doc.id)` could also be a lot of other things, but it's python code, because `t-att-src` will be evaluated later.

Biggest concerns and things i can't answer right now:

- how to handle an url within an url, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737935/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-pass-urls-as-url-parameters)
- how will this escaped url work with Odoo's barcode generator
- where to get the url from: can it be hardcoded or do you want to get it dynamically on conditions?

Answer (score 0):

There are apps that add the QR code of the document URL in the pdf report.
When you scan the QR code, it will redirect you to a specific document.

Here are the apps: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/browse?search=ehcs_qr_code