# Why does a URL-like query param changed from "http://..." to "https://..."?

Tags: javascript, http, https, query-string

I want to send an unique constraint, which unfortunately looks like an URL.
My unique constraint string looks like this: 
 `http://192.168.1.1:8086/testOrg/testBucket`

I pass this UC in the query param of a delete request: 
`https://localhost:5001/api/settings?uc=https://192.168.1.1:8086/testOrg/testBucket`

The crazy thing, which i do not understand is the fact, that the URL of the UC changed from "**http**" to "**https**".

I tried to add letters in front of the UC, e.g. `UChttp://192.168.1.1:8086/testOrg/testBucket` but event this changed to "**https**".

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739132/7785337

Comment: thank you very much! I did not know this.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!

Comment: Whenever you are adding variable data to any string, your instinct should be 'how should this string be escaped'. Every format will have a unique way to do this, and you basically almost need to learn what function you need to encode something. Not doing so could lead to obvious bugs like this case, but also more subtle security bugs that only appear once someone starts messing with it.